# Seting object in request and retreving from jsp

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am using org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper for returning a Jason object. I kept the list in request but not able to access it from jsp. Is there any other way to do this?

```
       response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        try {
            ArrayList list = cservice.getPolicyList(lastName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(amount > 0){
            request.setAttribute("dataList", list);

            result =  "{\"success\": true,\"amount\"}";
        }else{
            result =  "{\"success\": false,\"message\": \"We could not find any records. Please verify your search criteria.\"}";
        }

        //Finally send the jason response                   
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        mapper.writeValue(out, result);
```

Comment: The code is from your jsp or from your servlet??, How do you get the value from the jsp could you post the code.

Comment: Don't `response.getOutputStream();` but forward to the JSP.

Comment: In JSP, I would like t ouse ArrayList list = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list"); I am geting null.

Comment: I cannot forward to jsp as this is a ajax call from jsp to servlet.

Comment: Above code is from Servlet